# Hide a program that is popping up after unplugging USB

Tags: usb, windows-11

I have a program running (hidden), but every time someone pulls the USB out of the laptop a message from the app comes popping up with `Do you want to restart the application?` And then the app restarts.
The program is WebCam Monitor, which monitors and protects my house.

Is there a way to force the program and popup to stay hidden?
Because if the `Ok` or `Decline` button is pushed at the moment the USB webcam is pulled, the monitoring software pops up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the program called, what does it normally do?

Comment: Does the dialog come up when any usb is disconnected, or just the webcam usb?

Comment: No only when the webcam usb is disconectet, its an message from the program itsellf.
Cant turn that off.

Comment: Epoxy the USB plug in place.

Comment: No the problem is not that the usb is faling out. But that I dont want other people see the notification and restart of the program if they take the laptop to do something.

Comment: You should tell the developer of the program.

Comment: You could use autohotkey to do this I believe.  I myself do not use it and could not tell you how but MANY MANY people here are experts at using it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell a given program it is not allowed to generate any prompts. If the developer added those prompts, the the developer will be the only one who could rewrite the code to allow the prompts to be suppressed.

The exception to this would be if the software is open source or you have other means of accessing the source code.

Either the developer has a function supporting this, or they don't.